# What kind of graphic employment is (in general) better paid?

Tags: business

I will try to be as specific as possible.

I am a junior graphic designer (2.5 years of experience). I would like to ask more experienced colleagues - would you recommend working as a freelancer, or getting hired in a company (in terms of potential salary)?

I got a job offer from https://www.netguru.co/ - they pay well, cooperate with big clients - they seem to be a great company in terms of how I could develop my skills.

However, I wonder if I could earn more if I decided to invest more in portfolio, clients outreach and so on.

It is not a strict "graphic advice" question, but I thought many professionals are here so it is a great place to ask such thing as I am on the crossroads now.

Comment: Question is do you already have a pool of clients enough to support you. If so then freelancing may be better if not then taking a job is better.

Comment: There are too many variables for this question to have a definitive answer, but one short answer would be “management”. I would strongly recommend making decisions based on factors other than money. I’ve had high paying jobs that made me miserable and periods of patchy freelance work where I was relatively poor, but very happy with loads of free time. Money isn’t everything.